# HAVING ANY in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I'm looking for the right syntax to filter groups (i.e. groups of rows that have been `GROUP BY`'d) where at least one row fits a certain condition.

For example if I wanted to select a group where at least one row has a fold_change value greater than 4, I would expect this to work:

```
HAVING ANY(rnaseq.fold_change) > 4
```

But I get the error

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "ANY"

---

I suspect this is because [Postgres requires the constant value to be on the left](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN19686), but if I do it the other way around I get this error

```
4 < ANY(rnaseq.fold_change)
```

> ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side

---

The only way I can get it to work is using array_agg like this:

```
4 < ANY(array_agg(rnaseq.fold_change))
```

But that syntax is fairly confusing compared to the first example and having to manually create an array for each group doesn't sound efficient at all.

Is there a proper way to do HAVING ANY in postgres?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use either:

```
HAVING MAX(rnaseq.fold_change) > 4
```

or the Postgres aggregate function **[`bool_or`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)**:

```
HAVING bool_or( rnaseq.fold_change > 4 )
```